# Thead.join() not helping in printing a string only after all the threads are finished

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, function, delay

I am currently trying to write a function which achieves the following:

- Takes all of the messages from the list 'messages', in random order, while making sure none of them are repeated.
- Prints them after a delay of a random amount of seconds in the range between 1 - 10 seconds.
- After all the threads are done, it prints a string "Printing is finished. You will be returned to the main menu in 5 seconds."

The problem I am encountering, however, is that the string "Printing is finished..." is being printed in-between the random messages, rather than after them.

My confusion stems from the fact that the .join() method works perfectly for a similar function. The string is printed only after all the threads are finished. The main difference between them is that the other function doesn't take any random input. Instead, it iterates over a global dictionary called 'messages_and_times' in which the key:value pairs come from the user inputs for message and the amount of seconds (user input is handled by yet another function).

Below you can see the function option_3(), which does not work, and the function option_2(), which does work. At the very bottom I will include the whole code for further reference.

Could someone please help me understand what I'm doing wrong?

Thank you in advance for your time and assistance.

P.S.
The `clear()` function is there to clear the terminal display after every input.

The non-working function:

```
def option_3():
    clear()
    messages = ["message_1", "message_2", "message_3", "message_4", "message_5",
                "message_6", "message_7", "message_8", "message_9", "message_10"]

    print("Printing initialized:\n")

    def threading_function(message, seconds):
        time.sleep(seconds)
        print(message)

    for message in messages:
        randomized_messages = []
        random_index = random.randint(0, len(messages) - 1)
        randomized_messages.append(messages.pop(random_index))
        for msg in randomized_messages:
            t = Thread(target=threading_function, args=(msg, random.choice(range(1,11))))
            t.start()


    t.join()
    time.sleep(0.5)
    print(
        "\nPrinting is finished. You will be returned to the main menu in 5 seconds.")
    time.sleep(5)
    main_menu()
```

---

The working function:

```
def option_2():
    global messages_and_times

    clear()
    print("Printing initialized:\n")

    def threading_function(message, seconds):
        time.sleep(seconds)
        print(message)

    for message, seconds in messages_and_times.items():
        t = Thread(target=threading_function, args=(message, seconds))
        t.start()

    t.join()
    time.sleep(0.5)
    print(
        "\nPrinting is finished. You will be returned to the main menu in 5 seconds.")
    time.sleep(5)
    main_menu()
```

---

The entire main_menu() function:

```
import os
import random
clear = lambda: os.system('cls')

messages_and_times = {}


def main_menu():

    def option_1():
        global messages_and_times

        clear()
        message = input(
            "Please type in a message you would like to add to the list:")
        clear()
        seconds = int(
            input("Please type in the time of delay for this message:"))
        messages_and_times[message] = seconds

        def create_dictionary():

            clear()
            answer = input(
                "Would you like to add another message? (yes/no)").lower()
            if answer == "yes":
                option_1()
            elif answer == "no":
                clear()
                print("You will now be returned to the main menu.")
                time.sleep(1.5)
                main_menu()
            else:
                clear()
                print("Please answer yes or no.")
                time.sleep(1.5)
                create_dictionary()
        create_dictionary()

    def option_2():
        global messages_and_times

        clear()
        print("Printing initialized:\n")

        def threading_function(message, seconds):
            time.sleep(seconds)
            print(message)

        for message, seconds in messages_and_times.items():
            t = Thread(target=threading_function, args=(message, seconds))
            t.start()

        t.join()
        time.sleep(0.5)
        print(
            "\nPrinting is finished. You will be returned to the main menu in 5 seconds.")
        time.sleep(5)
        main_menu()

    def option_3():
        clear()
        messages = ["message_1", "message_2", "message_3", "message_4", "message_5",
                    "message_6", "message_7", "message_8", "message_9", "message_10"]
        randomized_messages = []
        print("Printing initialized:\n")

        def threading_function(message, seconds):
            time.sleep(seconds)
            print(message)

        for message in messages:
            random_index = random.randint(0, len(messages) - 1)
            randomized_messages.append(messages.pop(random_index))
        for msg in randomized_messages:
            t = Thread(target=threading_function, args=(msg, random.choice(range(1,11))))
            t.start()


        t.join()
        time.sleep(0.5)
        print(
            "\nPrinting is finished. You will be returned to the main menu in 5 seconds.")
        time.sleep(5)
        main_menu()


    clear()
    selection = 0
    while selection == 0:
        print(("-" * 15) + "MAIN MENU" + ("-" * 15) + "\n")
        print("1: Input a message and a corresponding time of delay before its display.")
        print("2: Print your customized list of messages.")
        print("3: Print random messages with random delays.\n")

        selection = int(input(
            "Please select one of the options, by typing in the corresponding number:"))

        if selection == 1:
            option_1()
        elif selection == 2:
            option_2()
        elif selection == 3:
            option_3()
        else:
            clear()
            print("Please select from options 1 - 3.\n")
            time.sleep(1.5)
            main_menu()
```

Edit (final solutions for future reference):

Thanks to suggestions from Almog David, here's how I've modified my functions to work as intended. I hope this helps somebody browsing for a solution in the future.

Option_2():

```
 def option_2():
    global messages_and_times

    clear()
    threads = []
    print("Printing initialized:\n")

    def threading_function(message, seconds):
        time.sleep(seconds)
        print(message)

    for message, seconds in messages_and_times.items():
        t = Thread(target=threading_function, args=(message, seconds))
        t.start()
        threads.append(t)

    for t in threads:
        t.join()

    time.sleep(0.5)
    print(
        "\nPrinting is finished. You will be returned to the main menu in 5 seconds.")
    time.sleep(5)
    main_menu()
```

Option_3():

```
def option_3():
        clear()
        messages = ["message_1", "message_2", "message_3", "message_4", "message_5",
                    "message_6", "message_7", "message_8", "message_9", "message_10"]
        threads = []
        print("Printing initialized:\n")

        def threading_function(message, seconds):
            time.sleep(seconds)
            print(message)

        for message in messages:
            t = Thread(target=threading_function, args=(
                message, random.choice(range(1, 11))))
            t.start()
            threads.append(t)
        for t in threads:
            t.join()

        time.sleep(0.5)
        print(
            "\nPrinting is finished. You will be returned to the main menu in 5 seconds.")
        time.sleep(5)
        main_menu()
```

Comment: In the non-working version you have a `t.join()` following a couple of nested `for` loops, the inner-most of which does a `t = Thread(...)`, so the value of `t` when you do the `join()` is the last thread assigned to it. Is that what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you wait only for the last thread to join (because 't' variable is holding the last created Thread object when the loop ends) so the join function returns when the last thread is completed and the program continues.

I was able to reproduce this error even on option 2 by supplying:

```
messages_and_times = {"message_0": 3,
                  "message_1": 3,
                  "message_2": 1}
```

The result for the above configuration is:

```
message_2

Printing is finished. You will be returned to the main menu in 5 seconds.
message_0
message_1
```

What you should do to fix it is:

```
threads = []

for message, seconds in messages_and_times.items():
    t = Thread(target=threading_function, args=(message, seconds))
    t.start()
    threads.append(t)

for t in threads:
    t.join()
```

Comment: Ahh thank you so much. I've also noticed another mistake I've made. If I use a .pop() method, eventually the 'messages' list is left with only 5 entries and so is the 'randomized_messages' list. I'll edit my original post to include final solutions.

Comment: Yes you are correct i also noticed this behavior but i thought it was intentional.